# Any rules or fluff around a technomancer infected with HMHVV?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, technomancer, shadowrun

I've been toying with the idea of making a campaign's antagonist an HMHVV infected technomancer (AKA techno-ghoul). Is there anything in the various sourcebooks or official fluff that describes this in-detail? I'm looking to both avoid conflicting with any precedent, and to steal any good ideas.

Since the HMHVV grants astral-sensitivity, I wanted to extend that, and have a bad-guy who could create technology-spirits -  some sort of unholy union between a sprite and a spirit, something akin to a toxic or insect spirit, able to affect the matrix, and physically manifest itself within piles of discarded technology.

Comment: Rather interesting concept, curious about the implementation too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately there is.

Runner's Companion p83, description of different HMHVV types:

> When the character awakens, she has lost all Resonance and technomancer abilities

(rephrased a bit differently in 3 different infection types).

So much for *infected* technomancers.

**BUT**, and this is a really **BIG BUT**, I think you could do without this combo.

- nothing prevents an *infected* from being a hacker.
- nothing prevents an *infected* from being a shaman worshipping the <s>Machine Spirit</s> aforementioned sprite-spirit fusion and helping them procreate.
- nothing prevents a freshly-infected *technomancer* to remain in good relationship with its AI's/free sprites and to work from there.

Comment: Thanks for the legwork - looks like I'll need to change-up my strategery.